# How to completely purge QGIS?

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu

I have problems with QGIS 2 crashing and first I tried to purge and reinstall it. So I removed `.qgis2` folder from `~/` and did all that `apt-get remove --purge qgis` etc., so commands like

`dpkg -l | grep qgis`, `dpkg -l | grep qgs`, `find / -name '*qgis*'`, `find / -name '*qgs*'`

were all giving me empty results. That means there was no single file or directory on my Ubuntu 16.04 containing "qgis" or "qgs" in it's name.

So I proceeded with installing QGIS and to my surprise all of my custom preferences were preserved - that means added repositories and global variables that I set before.

So how can I purge QGIS completely, so there is no single byte of QGIS-related data on my disk? Note I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Did you check manually e.g. for the QGIS2.conf in .config/QGIS ?

Comment: well, that was it, looks like I was searching case sensitive. Thanks a lot @BerndV., please post it as an answer and I'll accept it!